# Angular Ng-option is not working if the option value is same

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a scenario, where I will filter and show the title and id as a option value in a select box.

I have a if-else condition inside the ng-options, which will handles whether to show the title or not.

Now am facing an issue, If the selected title and previous selected title are same then the ng-change option is not getting triggered.

The expected output should be.

1. If title is available in the json response then display the title and id.
2. If title is not available then display only id.
3. If selected title and previous selected title are equal , then match the condition with id and display the drop down with selected title and selected id, with working ng-select.

This is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="model.selected" ng-options="item.Title as item.Title? (item.Title + '-' + item.ID) : ('' + item.ID) for item in items"></select>
  <p>Selected: {{model.selected}}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.model = {
      selected: 'Chicago'
    }
    $scope.items = [{
        ID: '000.000.0001',
        Title: 'Chicago'
      },
      {
        ID: '000.000.0002',
        Title: 'Chicago'
      },
      {
        ID: '000.000.0003',
        Title: 'Washington'
      },
      {
        ID: '000.000.0004'
      }
    ];
  });
```

Comment: Why would you have two options with the same value?

Comment: @yBrodsky: There are chances because this title is dynamic and any one can have any name

Comment: I think you can't do that in the ng-options. In addition, the last value of your array doesn't even have a Title which you are using as value (ng-options="item.Title as), that is also breaking the select. What you can do is loop through the options and sanitize them. Remove elements without a Title and create a new attribute so you use to display.

Comment: @yBrodsky: Can you please help me out with an example.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5hxL7sb2/ What I did was remove from the array the items that don't have a Title. (bare in mind that if they don't have a Title you don't even need them in the select, they can't be selected). And then modified the " as ..." of your select.

Comment: See [Which is correct: "bare in mind" or "bear in mind"?](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-bare-in-mind-or-bear-in-mind).